# Add objects from my class to dictionaries and be able to get specific attributes from the objects in the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a method in my class that creates new objects from user-inputs and adds them to a dictionary (this may not be the best way of doing this, appreciate any input). Further I want to be able to still get the attributes of the objects in the dictionary for other functions in a simple way which to me is the hardest part.

I have looked around for any similar problems but cant seem to find any, while this issue seems pretty general to me I believe there is an easy way to do this or i'm just doing something very wrong. If i just add the objects to a dictionary I just the "position" of the object but I want the specific attributes added to the dictionary based on name and species as given below.

```
animals = {}
class animal:

  def __init__(self,name,species):
    self.name = name
    self.species = species


  def dict(self,name,species):
    #i want this function to create and add new objects to animals
```

For a given user input of name and species I would like for the output of dict() to add the new object to a dictionary and then somehow for example being able to loop through the dictionary for the names of all animals in the dictionary. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: what is wrong with `animals[name] = animal(...)`?

Comment: I find your question a little bit confusing. Creating a class object with user input looks pretty forward? Also if you have a lot of actions with a dictionary full of animals, consider to create a new class AnimalGroups (example name). Also important that your class name starts with a capital.

Comment: I want to be able to for instance "search" for the names of all of the animals in the dictionary for a given one, but I don't know how find the attributes of the objects created from the class in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but you can use a class method to effectively make a new constructor that also takes a dictionary and mutate that dictionary inside

```
class Animal:

    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    @classmethod
    def init_and_track(cls, dict_, name, species):
        a = cls(name, species)
        dict_[name] = a
```

and use as so

```
animals = {}
Animal.init_and_track(animals, 'sally', 'horse')
```

as for getting user inputs, you could instead do something like

```
 @classmethod
 def init_and_track(cls, dict_):
    name = input('name: ')
    species = input('species: ')
    a = cls(name, species)
    dict_[name] = a
```

where the name and species are made by the user upon calling this method. I am not sure exactly what you want and why you want it this way but this is what I believe you are asking for.

---

Your comment suggests your original question was an [`xy`-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - how about something like this. Define your animal using [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) because it is just a holder for some data (assuming python 3.7)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass 


@dataclass 
class Animal:

    name: str 
    species: str

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f'{self.name} the {self.species} says hi')
```

the `: <...>` you see are type [annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Then define a new class to keep track of these animals.

```
class Zoo:

    def __init__(self):
         self.animals = []

    def add_animal(self):
        print('adding a new animal to the zoo')
        name = input('what is it\'s name? ')
        species = input('what species is it? ')
        a = Animal(name, species)
        self.animals.append(a)

    def find_by_name(self, name):
        animals_with_name = [a for a in self.animals if a.name == name]
        return animals_with_name

    def find_by_species(self, species):
        return [a for a in self.animals if a.species = species]
```

If you only wanted to keep track of one attribute like by species, you are right that a dictionary would be best. If you wanted to keep track of more attributes do something like

```
def find_by_attribute(self, attribute_name, value):
    return [a for a in self.animals if getattr(a, attribute_name) == value]
```

to avoid writing duplicate code. This should help get you started

Comment: First off, thank you so much for the reply and sorry if the question was confusing but my main issue is that I want to keep track of all the animals at the zoo and for example be able to find all the animals of a specific species. My thought is that a dictionary is the way to go but I don't know how to find for example the name of an object i have added to the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much!